# How do I remove rows in a data frame that contain NAs but leave exceptions for certain rows?

Tags: r

My df has about 17,000 rows (genes) and 200 columns (patients), I need to remove the genes that contain NAs, but 12 of them are important for my analysis so instead of removing them, I'm going to remove any patients that have an NA for any of these 12 genes.

How would I code something that? (Couldn't find any similar questions, sorry)

Comment: The na.omit function could be useful.

Comment: Right - but how do I apply it to 17,000 rows with exceptions for 12 specific ones?

Comment: Perhaps create a subset for the 12 patients as a new data frame. A second subset without the 12 patients. Apply na.omit to the second data frame to generate the third data frame. After that, use cbind to combine the first and third data frame.

Comment: Because you did not provide an example dataset, it is difficult for others to provide solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to include a toy example in your questions and the result of what you would expect. It helps users to answer your question without having to write a toy example. I did a small example with 5 patients, 5 important genes and 5 less important ones.

You can do what you want in two steps. First, we remove patients with `colSums` and `is.na`. In other words, we are counting how many `NA`s per column only for the important genes rows (rows 1:5). We only keep the columns where the number of `NA`s is zero. Then we simply do an `na.omit` to remove genes with `NA`s.

```
#Example data:
df1 <-data.frame(matrix(sample(letters,50,replace=TRUE),ncol=5))
colnames(df1) <-paste0("patient",1:5)
rownames(df1) <-c(paste0("important",1:5),paste0("lessimportant",6:10))
df1[2,4] <-NA;df1[7,1] <-NA;df1[9,5] <-NA #add NA for example

df1
                patient1 patient2 patient3 patient4 patient5
important1             m        f        d        t        m
important2             t        v        j     <NA>        d
important3             s        n        h        t        p
important4             h        h        t        n        i
important5             x        t        c        r        p
lessimportant6         y        f        b        a        h
lessimportant7      <NA>        o        h        n        a
lessimportant8         o        g        o        l        x
lessimportant9         m        p        f        d     <NA>
lessimportant10        n        a        h        u        a

#to remove NAs according to your specifications
df1 <-df1[,colSums(is.na(df1[1:5,]))==0] # remove patients with NA in important genes
df1 <-na.omit(df1) #remove genes with NA

#result
df1
                patient1 patient2 patient3 patient5
important1             m        f        d        m
important2             t        v        j        d
important3             s        n        h        p
important4             h        h        t        i
important5             x        t        c        p
lessimportant6         y        f        b        h
lessimportant8         o        g        o        x
lessimportant10        n        a        h        a
```